# Meteor server stops if there is a mistake in less with no errors

Tags: reactjs, meteor

So, whenever I make a minor mistake in less, the whole app crashes and server stops with out any errors in the console. I have tried searching on Google for this issue, but haven't found anything useful.

I am relatively new to react so I may not be able to describe the problem in detail or show any useful code. 
Any additional questions, or help is welcome. Thank you

Comment: What do you consider `minor mistake in less` ? If your less code contains syntax errors then the app will crash because Meteor always compiles all your code to a local build (see the `.meteor/local/build` folder) and it is a crucial behavior of a compiler to stop and throw errors if there is faulty syntax.

Comment: I understand that the compiler should stop, that is normal behavior. But the problem is it does not show where the error is.